# EWS exchange - null reference when casting NotificationEvent to ItemEvent

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get calendar notifications using stream listener.

All over internet the examples looks preaty much the same. But in my case when I cast NotificationEvent to ItemEvent to get ItemId, the cast runs well but object is always **null**. Internally the `NotificationEvent` is FolderEvent (which does not have ItemId), anyway at all examples it is always casted to ItemEvent.

```
    public void OnNotificationEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (NotificationEvent notification in args.Events)
        {
            ItemEvent itemEvent = notification as ItemEvent;
            ... //Other code goes here
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what types you have subscribed to both Item and Folder notification events should be expected so you should be first checking the type of notification eg

```
        if (notification is ItemEvent) 
    { 
        // The NotificationEvent for an e-mail message is an ItemEvent. 
        ItemEvent itemEvent = (ItemEvent)notification; 

    } 
    else 
    { 
        // The NotificationEvent for a folder is an FolderEvent. 
        FolderEvent folderEvent = (FolderEvent)notification; 

    }
```

Folder Event notifications basically let you know that something has changed in the folder and what the underlying Unread Item count is. You should then received separate ItemEvent depending on the type of change.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: It is just as you say, thanks. Anyway, may I just suscribe to ItemEvent and ignore FolderEvent? How?

Comment: No you can't do that because your subscribing to a type of change eg when subscribed to Modification events you will get a notification for both the Folder and Item, you just need to ignore the FolderEvent if you don't need them.